# Validation of 'input type file' and 'dropdown options' inside form (using angularjs) Possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, validation

I am still a newbie and learning `angularjs` which is fun and exciting. I have worked on the following plunker link. http://plnkr.co/edit/WiXEVIN6K63O50FhdzO2?p=preview

The above link is showing the validation of 2 select option. if either of these dropdown values are not selected, the submit button wont be active.

The code for this is as shown below.

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="preOpSelectController">
<form name="form">


  <select ng-model="bar.foo" ng-options="foo as foo for foo in fooarray"  required>
    <option ng-if="fooarray.length > 1" value="" selected>Choose</option>
  </select>


  <select ng-model="bar.foo1" ng-options="foo as foo for foo in fooarray1"  required>
    <option ng-if="fooarray.length > 1" value="" selected>Choose</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid" />


</form>
```

**Script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('preOpSelect', []);

app.controller('preOpSelectController', function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.bar = {};
$scope.bar1 = {};

$scope.fooarray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
$scope.fooarray1 = [ 12, 21, 32, 43, 54, 64];

$scope.trigger = function() {
 $timeout(function() {
   $('form.bad select').trigger('change');
 })
}
});
```

The second file is this- http://plnkr.co/edit/yya3vMoaTFiONU9wrFVw?p=preview

This shows how input type file is validated. The problem is i need to merge this file with the first one and show all the three inputs together. i.e. input type file and 2 dropdown selection. submit button should be active only when all the 3 file values are selected.

I am facing difficulty because the functions for first code is in normal controller file whereas input type file is in a directive. I am not able to merge the first file's code in a directive of the second link.

Can someone please let me help here.

Comment: what is the use of validFile directive? For validation of file types or just to check the value

Comment: i think it just checks if the file is empty or not.

Comment: required attribute does that for you (whether a file is selected or not)

Comment: yes harsh, but it gives html5 validation popup. i dont want to show tat pop up. instead i want to work on some function which will disable button if file is not selected

Comment: add novalidate attribute to form tag to avoid such validations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Harshs comment did help me to get through some barriers. i worked on it eventually and merged both these together and it worked like a charm. http://plnkr.co/edit/CYnhNUnT6aKdCwB65j5N
Please refer to the above plunker.

Here is the HTML code

```
 <form name="form" novalidate>

  <input type="file" ng-model="document" valid-file required>
  <select ng-model="activeItem.content" ng-options="foo as foo for foo in contentarray"  required>
    <option ng-if="contentarray.length > 1" value="" selected>Choose</option>
  </select>


  <select ng-model="activeItem.content1" ng-options="foo as foo for foo in content1array"  required>
    <option ng-if="content1array.length > 1" value="" selected>Choose</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid && (!form.$valid && 'invalid' || 'valid')"/>


</form>
```

Script file is as follows.

```
var app = angular.module('preOpSelect', []);

app.controller('preOpSelectController', function($scope, $timeout) {
$scope.content = {};
$scope.content1 = {};

$scope.contentarray = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
$scope.content1array = [ 12, 21, 32, 43, 54, 64];

$scope.trigger = function() {
 $timeout(function() {
   $('form.bad select').trigger('change');
 })
   }
});


preOpSelect.directive('validFile', function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, el, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$render = function () {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(el.val());
        };

        el.bind('change', function () {
            scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModel.$render();
            });
        });
    }
};
});
```

PS- if you wonder why i used a directive for input type file, here is the answer
I guess ngModelController doesn't currently support input type=file. Hence the issue can be solved with a custom directive.

Thank you all. Hope it helps someone in future too.

Comment: It will be helpful to others if you can explain the need for validFile directive

Comment: @Harsh- thanks. i updated the answer with the explaination. please have a look.

Comment: in version 1.2.12 of angular it is working without the directive

Comment: oh thats wat i was looking for. can u direct me to that link? i will have a look. thanks

Comment: You can try it on your plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/CYnhNUnT6aKdCwB65j5N just remove the directive and try to bind that model on the view